# Начисление Баллов после нажатия на кнопку

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! Есть две кнопки:
**1 кнопка: Запускает таймер**

```
<button id='111' onclick='onClick();'>Получить балл</button> 


 <span id='time'></span>
```

**2 кнопка: Начисляет Баллы после нажатия и сразу запускает таймер**

```
<div id='example' style=' display: none; '>
<input type='submit'name='222' value='Получить бонус'id='111' onclick='onClick();'>
```

Вопрос: Как сделать так чтобы 1 кнопка сразу после нажатия зачислило балл и запускало таймер?

Comment: Обе кнопки запускают одну функцию, чего Вы хотите?

Comment: Вы в бане чтоль? Нужно тоже подмышку сфоткать и на аву поставить.

Comment: Надо чтобы 1 кнопка зачислило балл, а вторая после истечения таймера итак зачисляет балл.

Comment: Приведите пример того, что есть (как что начисляет, мы-то не знаем) и что Вы **хотите** в итоге.

Comment: @Other Чтоб кнопка1 сначало  зачислил балл потом запустил таймер. Кнопка2 появляется после истечения времени(это работает)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сам разобрался. объединил кнопки.